# Multiple counts in a query

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm writing a query that counts company complaints. The query should count the total number of complaints from a company and also break it down into who called from the company to make the complaint. So an example output would be:

```
Company Ref  Company Name  Company Complaints  Caller       Caller Complaints
         11  Argos                         10  Steve                        8
         11  Argos                         10  JIM                          2
```

So as you can see the query counts the total number of complaints, then also breaks it down to who complained. So far I have everything perfect apart from the total count. My code is:

```
  SELECT COMPANYREF,
       COMPANY,    
  (SELECT COUNT(COMPANYREF)
   FROM XCALLSTABLE) AS CompanyCalls,
       CALLER,
       COUNT(*)
FROM XCALLSTABLE
JOIN XCUSTOMERTABLE ON (XCALLSTABLE.COMPANYREF = XCUSTOMERTABLE.CUSTREF)
JOIN XTELEPHONETABLE ON (XCUSTOMERTABLE.TELEPHONE = XTELEPHONETABLE.PHONENUMBER)
GROUP BY COMPANYREF,
         COMPANY,
         CALLER
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0  ;
```

Some sample output for the current code is:

```
Company Ref  Company Name  Company Complaints  Caller       Caller Complaints

        145  Comfiture Traders            500  Alexis Patel                 4
```

The issue here is the total count for the company just counts every row, whereas I'm trying to count the occurances of that company appearing in the column.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Using sstan's code gave a result of

```
 111    Medusa Shipping 4   Lily Morgan 5
 111    Medusa Shipping 4   Ruby Walker 6
```

Whereas the result should be

```
 111    Medusa Shipping 11  Lily Morgan 5
 111    Medusa Shipping 11  Ruby Walker 6
```

Comment: I think you'll be OK if you add MAX (...) around the subselect for CompanyCalls.  Like SELECT COMPANYREF,  COMPANY, MAX ((SELECT ... FROM  XCALLSTABLE)) as CompanyCalls ...        But you may also need JOIN on your subselect, to ensure same sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing this, but the following query should work:

```
SELECT companyref,
       company,
       CompanyCalls,
       caller,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT c.companyref,
               company,
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.companyref) AS CompanyCalls,
               caller
          FROM xcallstable c
          JOIN xcustomertable ct
            ON ct.custref = c.companyref
          JOIN xtelephonetable t
            ON t.phonenumber = ct.telephone)
 GROUP BY companyref, company, CompanyCalls, caller
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Comment: hey, cheers for the help. The code looks good however its counting occurrences of the companyname in the result as opposed to counting occurrences in the table.

Comment: I don't understand the difference. Can you edit your post with an example of how my query differs from the expected result?  I was basing myself off the example you provided.

Comment: I think I understand the problem.  I adjusted the query in my answer.